# SQL Server 2008 - Intermittent error 18456 with sa

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I have an application that uses a group of SQL 2008 databases. For some reason, the main database intermittently throws a series of 18456 errors (Login failed - failed to open the explicitly specified database). This causes the application to wig out and often crash. In the SQL server logs, the server throws dozens of events in a short period of time, typically like this:

```
Login succeeded for user 'sa'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '[my_db]'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Whenever this happens, it happens repeatedly. I count 73 total events over a 4 minute period in the last incident.

Here is what the application is logging:

> Cannot open database "[my_db]" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'sa'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "[my_db]" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'sa'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, 
>    SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

The connection string is as follows:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=[my_db];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=[password]
```

The sa login is mapped to dbo, of course, and its default database is set to master. I've checked that the dbo login has the db_owner role assigned on this database. The permissions on the ldf/mdf files are default and the logged in user has access to them. Those files are also exempted in the anti-virus software so they're not being locked up by that.

What the heck am I missing here?

Comment: Why is your application connecting with the `sa` account in the first place? It should be using a `LOGIN` and `USER` that has appropriate permissions for the task it needs to perform. (Also, I *assume* you're aware that both SQL Server 2008 and Windows 7 are completed unsupported.)

Comment: Have you tried logging in as yourself instead of sa? You would switch from using `UserId` and `Password` to `TrustedConnection = True;`

Comment: @Lamu /shrug. I didn't write this app, I'm just keeping it alive on a wing and a prayer. I could change it down the road but I don't think that's the root issue here. And yeah, I know 08/Win7 are EOL. But - gotta use the tools we have, not the ones I wish we had.

Comment: @jfiggins Ok, so I can't recreate the error on demand, which is complicating the troubleshooting. Also, this app runs in Windows using a shared domain account as there's a rotating cast of users running it on a single system. Ideally, I don't want to use that account in the connection string as well. 

That said, notably, I can connect in SSMS using my own account without issue, but that might just be because I've never tried at the same time as whatever this issue is, is happening.

Comment: The fact that it's the `sa` account failing, and that the error is saying *"Failed to open the explicitly specified database "* implies the connection was successful to the instance, but the connection to the database failed. Perhaps the database is in `SINGLE_USER` or a restoring state?

Comment: @Olylo thanks for checking. The reason I wanted to see if you could do that is there could be a setting that only allows windows auth and not sql auth. Right click your database(logged in as yourself) then click `Properties > Security > Server Authentication`. Check if it says **Windows Authentication Mode** or **SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode**

Comment: @lamu The database is in MULTI_USER, and I've not seen any log indications that it would be in a restoring state. I do, however, see a few logs stating that the MDF file is locked by another process. These don't happen often or coincide with every instance of the login failing, but they seem to precede it (i.e. the MDF is locked and then logins alternately succeed and fail as mentioned until the server is restarted).

Comment: @jfiggins Thanks! The server is in mixed mode.

Comment: You will need to spend some time monitoring the instance. Just because the database is multi-user NOW doesn't mean someone or some process did not change it in the past when the error occurred. And if you see messages in a log about the physical file being locked, you really need to investigate more thoroughly what is happening with your system. Is your database set to auto-close?

Comment: @SMor I've been running a trace with profiler for a few days and haven't really pulled out anything useful, although I did narrow it to login-related events so maybe I just excluded something of note in that vein. The DB *is* set to auto-close right now.

Comment: Seen some crazy behavior in the past when the Auto-Close is on for the database.  Try setting it to OFF and see if anything changes.  I would also double check your anti-virus exclusion list and make sure there are no sql related files being scanned.

Comment: Right on. I did some research and elected to go ahead and turn off auto close. We will see if it makes a difference! Thanks.